# Is there a method to know when a tooltip will appear on a NSImageView?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nsview, nsimageview

I'd like to know if there's a method that get's called before a tooltip is displayed. I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No!!!
However you can create your own subclass of NSView with -mouseEntered() events.